# Is there any log to find why Struts2 application is giving HTTP 404 error

Tags: struts2, tomcat7, web.xml

I am migrating my web application from struts1 to strust2 (struts-core-2.3.16.3) on Tomcat server in Eclipse IDE.I have followed the Apache struts2 documention for migration.My directoey structure looks fine and whatever jars are required for struts2 has been included while removing the strust1 jars. When i run my application,the webapp is getting loaded but it gives http error 404 for the first filter defined in web.xml.
I was trying to find any error logs but could not see any log apart from tomcat access log.
Is there any way to see what is happening with my filters and filter mappings in web.xml through some logs?

Comment: It should be there, you have with tomcat server configuration.

Comment: Please post your web.xml